# mod_rewrite changing real URLs

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?a=$1&app=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is suppose to make all URLs search engine and user friendly, but the problem is that if someone goes to http://pattersoncode.ca/realurlhere/ it redirects them to an error page even though it's a real directory. Is there anyway to stop this? It must be thinking they are trying to go to http://pattersoncode.ca?a=realurlhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because of incorrect regular expression in this line:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?a=$1 [L]
```

Which is matching 0 or more characters until `/` is found. Change that to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /?a=$1 [L]
```

And problem will be fixed. In my answer I have made trailing slash options so both `/realurlhere/` and `/realurlhere` will be supported.